# Show all Tags in each post

Tags: custom-post-types, tags

I have created a new post type named "Project". And I registered 1 taxonomy "Tags" in it as follows:

https://pastecode.xyz/view/844258b1

I entered the tags into 1 article in post type "Project".

If you want to enter an article, it will display all the tags in that article.

Can someone help me. Thank you!

Comment: Please include the code in your post and highlight it. What values does this link have as soon as it goes 404?

Answer (score 1):

Considering you mention having registered a custom taxonomy instead of using the native tags, the functions `the_tags()` and `get_tags` will not work.

you need to get your custom taxonomy terms by using `get_the terms()`. Usage is not much different from using native tags, but you have to pass the post_type as a variable.
See the Wordpress codex on this: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/

Answer (score 0):

You have to be careful when creating a custom post type with taxonomy and the same namespace "tags", since tags are already registered by WordPress default for the post type posts. Maybe the renaming of the taxonomy to project-tags or something else would make sense. Otherwise the taxonomy will be mixed up by WordPress.

To show all tags you can use PHP:

```
the_tags('<ul class="taglist"><li>', '</li><li>', '</li></ul>');
```

Note: This function must be within the loop (archive.php or single.php).

Comment: Hi, I tried but my tags are not displayed. I created a single-project.php file with the following content:

https://pastecode.xyz/view/fd5d5bed

This is my website link.

https://phuckhangan.com/du-an/intercontinental-phu-quoc/

Answer (score 0):

Check out `get_the_tag_list()` to retrieve all the tags:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_tag_list

### Examples:

```
$separate_meta = __( ', ' );
echo $tags_list = get_the_tag_list( '', $separate_meta );
```

### OR:

```
<?php
 $tags = get_tags();
 if ($tags) {?>
  <ul class="tags">
  <?php
    foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    echo '<li><a href="' . get_tag_link( $tag->term_id ) . '" 
    title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $tag->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $tag->name.'</a></li>';
  }
  ?>
  </ul>
<?php }?>
```